# How to Accomplish this type of Design in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I can make it by keeping Listview loaded with images in one side and layout in another side. but how can I hide the listview layout divider to give a feel like Merged one? Any tutorials are greatly appreciated.

> [image]